# more efficient way to code this in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am building a watch customizer for school, im pretty new to javascript, this code works but its lengthy, and i  will need to add a lot more colours. is there a more efficient way to code this?

each color change is being called from buttons if that helps.

thanks for any help in advance.

```
   ///////////////////////////////////////// Face
  function ChangeFaceRG()
    {
    document.getElementById('face').src = "parts/faces/face roesGold.png";
    };
 function ChangeFaceG()
    {
    document.getElementById('face').src = "parts/faces/face gold.png";
    };
 function ChangeFaceS()
    {
    document.getElementById('face').src = "parts/faces/face silver.png";
    };
///////////////////////////////////////// Frame
  function ChangeFrameRG()
    {
    document.getElementById('frame').src = "parts/frames/frame rosegold.png";
    };
 function ChangeFrameG()
    {
    document.getElementById('frame').src = "parts/frames/frame gold.png";
    };
 function ChangeFrameS()
    {
    document.getElementById('frame').src = "parts/frames/frame silver.png";
    };

    //////////////////////// Hands
  function ChangeHandsRG()
    {
    document.getElementById('hands').src = "parts/hands/hands rose gold.png";
    };
 function ChangeHandsG()
    {
    document.getElementById('hands').src = "parts/hands/hands gold.png";
    };
 function ChangeHandsS()
    {
    document.getElementById('hands').src = "parts/hands/hands silver.png";
    };
////////////////////////////////////////// straps
  function ChangeStrapsRG()
    {
    document.getElementById('straps').src = "parts/straps/straps rose gold.png";
    };
 function ChangeStrapsG()
    {
    document.getElementById('straps').src = "parts/straps/straps gold.png";
    };
 function ChangeStrapsS()
    {
    document.getElementById('straps').src = "parts/straps/straps silver.png";
    };
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
function Change(folder, part, color) {
  document.getElementById(part).src = "part/" + folder + "/" + part + " " + color + ".png" ;
}
```

usage:

```
Change('hands', 'hand', 'rose gold');
Change('frames', 'frame', 'silver');
Change('straps', 'strap', 'gold');
Change('faces', 'face', 'silver');
```

Should work, I think.

Comment: I ended up using your solution, thanks a ton! I changed some of the file paths too, which allowed me to it down some more.

Answer (score 2):

**Consider a more generic approach**

Since all of your calls seem to do the same thing: target an image and set the source for it, you could likely refactor this out into a single function :

```
function SetImage(id, imgSrc) {
    // Find the image by it's `id` attribute and then set the source for that image
    document.getElementById(id).src = imageSrc;
}
```

This would allow you to just specific the `id` of the element that you are targeting and then the path for your given image :

```
<!-- Example usage -->
<button onclick='SetImage("face","parts/faces/face roesGold.png")'>Change Face</button>
```

Comment: This is a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass arguments to the function to make it more reusable/modular.

```
function ChangeHands(type) {
  document.getElementById('hands').src = `parts/hands/hands${type}.png`
}
```

Then you can call `ChangeHands('rosegold.png')`

You can do this for each of the functions, ChangeFace, ChangeHands, ChangeFrame, and ChangeStraps. Cheers and great question!

Comment: One problem with this approach is that the ID changes. Would work if you include a second parameter for ID though.

Comment: @Korgrue correct, as this is not perfectly tailored to OP's problem, just a suggestion of the approach I would take to modularize :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're using es2015:

```
// Config object, here you create a map between the id and the path
const CONFIG = {
    face: 'faces/face',
    frame: 'frames/frame',
    hands: 'hands/hands',
    straps: 'straps/straps'
}

// Get the correct path based on the provided type and color
const getPath = (type, color) => `parts/${type} ${color}.png`;

// Apply transformation with the path obtained from the `getPath` function 
const change = function (type, color) {
    document.getElementById(type).src = getPath(CONFIG.type, color);
}

// Example usage:
change('face', 'roseGold');
```

Otherwise (if you're not using es2015) you can replace the functions to be something like this:

```
function getPath (type, color) {
    return ['parts/', type, ' ', color, '.png'].join('');
}

function change (type, color) {
    document.getElementById(type).src = getPath(CONFIG.type, color);
}
```

Or just concatenate string with '+' operand.

This approach tries to have smaller functions and ensures that each has a single responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow isn't a good place for such questions, because it could be solved in infinite different ways. But, here you are, this is how I would do it:

```
var arrayWithPaths = [
    "parts/hands/hands silver.png",
    "parts/straps/straps rose gold.png",
    //and all other paths here
];

function change(what, toWhat){
    document.getElementById(what+'').src = arrayWithPaths[toWhat];
}
```

`what` is a string with id of object you want to change. You create array with all paths of images you want to use. Then you can create `toWhat` variable to specify which one do you want to use calling `change` function.

Answer (score 0):

For next level strats crate and array of all your conditions and loop through it.

```
ids = new arrary [id1, id2, id3, etc];
srcs = new arrary [src1, src2, src3, etc];
function setImage(id, imgSrc) {
    document.getElementById(id).src = imageSrc;
}
for(i=0; i<ids.length;i++){

setImage(id[i], src[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

arraies and cycles

```
var ids = ["face", "frame", "hands", "straps"]
var colors = ["rose gold", "gold", "silver"] 

ids.forEach(function(id, i, ids) {
     colors.forEach(function(color, i, colors) {
            document.getElementById(id).src = "parts/hands/hands " + color +".png";
     });
});
```